# How to intercept a request in Apache AsyncHttpClient?

Tags: java, asynchttpclient

Is there a way to intercept a request made by AsyncHttpClient and do some operations based on the request data.

I want to do something like this:

```
    interceptor = new Interceptor(){
        process(request){
           //do something  
        }
    }
    
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
```

is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using 'filters'.

```
AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder configBuilder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder();
configBuilder.addResponseFilter(new ResponseFilter() {
    public FilterContext filter(FilterContext ctx) throws FilterException {
              //do something
        }
    }
});
AsyncHttpClient c = new AsyncHttpClient(configBuilder.build());
```

Similarly you can add a request filter

```
configbuilder.addRequestFilter(RequestFilterImpl);
```